# Tensor product with a lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, lie-groups, tensor-products

Let $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Bbb C$ be $\Bbb R$-linearly independent.

Let $\Gamma=\Bbb{Z}\omega_1\oplus \Bbb Z\omega_2$. What is $\Gamma\otimes \Bbb R$? I imagine we are taking a tensor product as $\Bbb Z$-algebras? In which case is this not just $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context here?  How did it come up?  Why might you expect this to be something other than $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's apparently the tangent space at the identity of $\Bbb{C}/\Gamma$ but I have no idea why they have written it like this

Answer (score 0):

This might help

The tensor product of two dimensioned spaces A, B is  the simplest bilinear mapping M which for basis elements  a,b implies M(a,b) is a basis element of  the tensor product.

Apply the bilinearity to your problem :))